# Submit form dissapears from page after button click

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know why, but when I submit my form via the submit button it dissapears from the page and appears again only after a refresh. I tried some answers for similar issues here on stackoverflow, but nothing worked for me.

Here is my html :

```
<div id="lblNewAppPatient" class="menu-content">
        <form class="form-horizontal form" id="validate-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date">Date:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2 " class="dpckr" >
                <!-- <input class="form-control " id="date " name="date " placeholder="MM/DD/YYY " type="text "/> -->
                  <input id="date" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="date" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group ">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="text ">Hour:</label>

              </div>
              <div class="form-group ">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 ">
                  <button id="saveAppt" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see the problem with your code but try:

```
<input id="date" type="datetime" class="form-control datepicker" name="date" required>

 <input id="saveAppt" type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
```